# Partition Count in Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

Can we set the partition count of HazelCast IMap equal to number of nodes in the cluster?

What are the pitfalls?
I understand parallelism could be one.

Answer (score 1):

- As a consequence of single parallelism on a node, CPU won't be utilized well.
- If a new node is added, then it won't get assigned any partitions.
- If a node crashes, one of the remaining nodes will have two partitions, hence double CPU and memory load.